# Translation into react nodes

Tags: reactjs, internationalization

Instead of a translation like in this [basic example](https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/interpolation#basic)

```
{
    "key": "{{what}} is {{how}}"
}

i18next.t('key', { what: 'i18next', how: 'great' });
// -> "i18next is great"
```

I need a result like

```
<i>i18next</i> is <i>great</i>
```

as a react node to be rendered as

> *i18next* is *great*

I could generate the string `"<i>i18next</i> is <i>great</i>"` and use it with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, but that's ugly and dangerous.

I could split the key like

```
{
    "key1": "{{what}}",
    "key2": "is",
    "key3": "{{how}},
}
```

and use

```
const params = { what: 'i18next', how: 'great' };
return <>
   <i>{i18next.t('key1', params)}</i>
   {i18next.t('key2', params);}
   <i>{i18next.t('key3', params)}</i>
<>
```

which is safe, but even uglier. Moreover, in general, it requires to split every key with `n` arguments into `2*n+1` parts, which are related by nothing but a naming convention.

*We'd like to apply some formatting (not necessarily `<i>`; this was just an example) to all parameters, so we need a better solution.* I'm not looking for a library, i18next was just an example. *Any idea?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the [Trans Component](https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component#using-for-less-than-br-greater-than-and-other-simple-html-elements-in-translations-v-10-4-0)

A key looking like

```
key: "<0>{{what}}</0> is <2>{{how}}</2>"
```

can be used with

```
//  const what = "Pizza";
//  const how = "great";

<Trans i18nKey="key">
  <strong>{{ what }}</strong> is <i>{{ how }}</i>
</Trans>
```

and will produce: **Pizza** is *great*

Here is a playground [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-interpolation-tokens-react-118n-ld6q9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Hope it helps!

---

Other libraries do it differently - ex: [react-intl](https://github.com/formatjs/react-intl) can handle tags in the lang definitions - [this example](https://github.com/formatjs/react-intl#example)

Comment: Why `<0>` and `<2>`? I'm not getting the "Trans component".

Comment: Feels like a lot of guessing - and seems complicated. The docs offer some help for this: https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component#how-to-get-the-correct-translation-string. Looks like it's related to the words count.

Comment: That's it. Not that hard to find out, but given that it should be done by the translators... pretty crazy.

Comment: You link in react-intl doesn't make clear how to do the translation, but it was easy to find [richtext](https://github.com/formatjs/react-intl/blob/master/examples/Advanced.tsx#L21). I'm not sure whether I like anything of it, but that's probably all we can get.